# VSCODE cannot be logged in through github, only Microsoft's login option

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCODE cannot be logged in through github, only Microsoft's login option, which makes me unable to use Copilot

Before that, I disabled the GitHub identity authentication plugin (plug-in ID: vscode.github-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

same here. try delete this folder, backup first.

`C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User`